# Split the audio file by words

Tags: c#, .net, audio, split

There is audio file. Where few "words" with different time between them. I need to make as many .wav files as "words" in the file. Audio file is very clear, there is no noise, so it must be very easy to find the "words". Any ideas how to make it with C#? Maybe somebody knows any libraries?

Please check an example of waveform of the file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio is good. You'll be able to read the WAV header so you know what format was used to store the file.  Then you can just scan it and grab the regions where the entropy is higher.

https://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/612263

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks like the library that I need. Maybe you can give information that can help me to grab the regions where the entropy is higher? I am very new in it.

Comment: Well, let's suppose the WAV format is IEEE float.  That means that the signal should go from -1.0 to 1.0.  You'll have to decide a noise threshold, but to begin with we can say -0.1 to 0.1. Decide on a packet size...maybe 1024 samples. As long as every sample in a packet is within the noise threshold you can discard it. As soon as you encounter a packet that extends beyond noise levels you start recording your "word". You continue to record until you have a full packet within the noise threshold. Use a power of 2 for your packet size so you can play with FFTs. That is when the fun starts.

Comment: I'm curious what packet size and noise threshold levels you ended up with.

Comment: The noise is different for each file. I measure the noise in he begging of the file and than use it for splitting.